# Asset Pipeline on Rails 3.1.4 - Javascripts with right path but Stylesheets with wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, asset-pipeline

My Asset Pipeline seems to be broken...

It happened after an upgrade:

- **rails** from **'3.1.0'** to **'3.1.4'**
- **compass-rails** from **'1.0.0.rc.3'** to **'1.0.2'**
- **compass** from **'0.12.rc.1'** to **'0.12.1'**

On `<head>` JS's are under `/assets/` (correct path), but CSS's are going under `/stylesheets/` (wrong path). Real example:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My application.html.erb file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

How can I make 'styleesheet_link_tag' point to `/assets/` instead of `/stylesheets/`?

### EDIT

It was the `mobile-fu` gem, version `0.3.0` that was causing this odd behaviour.
I'm not using it anymore and problem is gone.

Comment: What are you currently passing to `stylesheet_link_tag`?

Comment: <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this to the application.erb file and check once?

```
config.assets.prefix = "/assets"
```

Comment: Already tried, with no luck at all. It's strange because JS files are served by Asset Pipeline, but CSS files aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `config/compass.rb` file. There maybe a css_path setting in there.

Comment: No config/compass.rb around here. =[